# TextView not updating from broadcast

Tags: android, textview

I'm developing an app where I will be getting a GCM notification and I'm sending a broadcast to my main activity so that I could update the UI. UI is updating if I have just opened the app and my Main activity is visible. But when I navigate to any other screen and come back to main activity, this time when i recieve the broadcast, the UI is not updating. I debugged and the code is executing fine and when I check the mText value for textview, its still showing the old value. I have also tried invalidate() and postInvalidate() methods. I dont now what I' doing wrong. Could someone please help me.

Note: I'm using setSelected(true) to apply marquee for my textviews.

```
Intent newi = new Intent("rating-changed"); 
newi.putExtra("message", "notify");       
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(newi); 

private void updateUI(final String pSong, final String pArt, final String cSong, final String cArt, final String nSong, final String nArt){

       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ImageView ivPrevSong = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPrevSong);
                ImageView ivCurSong = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivCurSong);
                ImageView ivNextSong = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivNextSong);

                TextView tvPrevSongName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPrevSongName);
                tvPrevSongName.setSelected(true);
                TextView tvCurrSongName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCurrSongName);
                tvCurrSongName.setSelected(true);
                TextView tvNextSongName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNextSongName);
                tvNextSongName.setSelected(true);

                tvPrevSongName.setText(pSong);
                tvCurrSongName.setText(cSong);
                tvNextSongName.setText(nSong);

                tvPrevSongName.refreshDrawableState();
                tvCurrSongName.refreshDrawableState();
                tvNextSongName.refreshDrawableState();

            }
        });

   }
```

Comment: Show the code what you have tried yet.

Comment: are you using local broadcast? post code of your activity

Comment: Intent newi = new Intent("rating-changed");
newi.putExtra("message", "notify");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(newi);

Comment: I'm updating ui from a runnable

Comment: Runnable running on UI thread or background thread? If the runnable is not on the UI thread, and you update a UI element with it, it should simply crash

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal I'm running the runnable on UI thread only

Comment: It seems that after coming back your activity is recreated and Local broadcast receiver refers to previous activity. Do you register and unregister receiver in corresponding activity's lifecycle callbacks (onStart, onStop) ?

Comment: Unregistering the receiver did the trick